# Sqoop: How to get counts of records for all tables before running the sqoop import

Tags: count, sqoop

I am trying to use sqoop to import all tables in a database from SQL relational database into hive. Before doing that, I would like to know how many records are in each of the tables in my source database.  This way, I can have how estimations of the impact to the source database and I want such impact to be small.

Is there a simple way to do that? I tried to use a query such as `select count(*) from dbname.tbname`.  It was not working. Here is what my sqoop looks like:

```
sqoop import -Dmapred.job.queue.name=$myqueue   
    --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://$svr;database=$db;username=$user;password=$pass" 
    --query "select count(*) from $tbname "  
    --target-dir $detdatadir/$filerecord -m3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add $CONDITIONS in --query "select count(*) from $tbname where \$CONDITIONS" and check

Comment: @Max577, please, show your error output

Comment: Why are you using import , I think sqoop eval you should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqoop command should be like this

```
sqoop eval -Dmapred.job.queue.name=$myqueue   
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://$svr;database=$db;username=$user;password=$pass" 
--query "select count(*) from $tbname"
```

Comment: Thanks LUZO for your help!     I have imported all the tables from an SQL databases without checking the size of each tables.  But I think your idea is good that we can use sqoop eval instead of sqoop import.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. Vinayak also suggested to use sqoop eval.

Comment: you can accept the answer if it works fine ... thanks